# Docker distributed cache

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile

I'm looking for a solution to share docker cache across multiple CI instances

The main use case is when building a new image using instance A, then building the same image using instance B from scratch, instead of having shard docker cache

This causes longer build / push time, and it can be shortened by sharing the cache

What I thought about is using `docker save` to .tar file, and `docker load` from the .tar file - each and every build new .tar file is created and shared between all the instance

Is there a more common solution for that problem?